# How can I create less than one turtle per point with NetLogo GIS extension?

Tags: gis, netlogo

I have **a Shapefile consisting of several points**, about 50 000 of them. I would like **to generate a certain amount of turtles using those points, but not all of them**. The number of turtles to create is defined by a global `globals [num-of-turtles]`, which can be modified on the interface.

By now, I have only managed to create one turtle per point and then killing the extra turtles with the following code (after loading the coordinate system, loading datasets, setting world envelope, etc.):

```
gis:create-turtles-from-points my-point-map turtles [
    set shape "house"
    set size 0.30
  ]
ask n-of (count turtles - num-of-turtles) turtles [die]
```

However, this seems a bit clumsy to me. Does someone come up with a way of creating just the pre-set amount of turtles?